# Error with brush style while working with Qgis2leaf

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2leaf

I am getting following error while working with QGIS2leaf. it saying that QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2' object has no attribute 'brushStyle'. I didn't understand why its coming . Full error what i am getting are as below

An error has occured while executing Python code:

AttributeError: 'QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2' object has no attribute 'brushStyle' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/patwardhan/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leafdialog.py", line 297, in export2leaf
    qgis2leaf_exec(self.outFileName, self.basemapName, self.basemapMeta, self.basemapAddress, self.width, self.height, self.extent, self.full_screen, self.layer_list, self.visible, self.opacity, self.encode2JSON,self.createcluster, self.webpage_name, self.webmap_head,self.webmap_subhead, self.legend,self.locate,self.address, self.precision, self.labels, self.labelshover, self.matchCRS, self.selected)
  File "C:/Users/patwardhan/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2leaf\qgis2leaf_exec.py", line 468, in qgis2leaf_exec
    if symbol.symbolLayer(0).brushStyle() == 0:
AttributeError: 'QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2' object has no attribute 'brushStyle'

Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.12.0-Lyon Lyon, cd9d645

Comment: do you have  a polygon-layer without filling?

Comment: yes i guess but its just border layer of canton. i overlapped it to display my address point . should i remove that polygon layer?

Comment: remove it or convert it to a polyline

Answer (score 3):

qgis2leaf is no longer being developed. See the Github repository at https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf. The last commit was on 20 April 2015. Use qgis2web instead, which is under active development - https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web.

Comment: i tried with qgis2web its working very nicely. thanks Tom